# Multi-city bike rental in Europe (NL, BE)

Tags: touring, europe

I'm considering a bike trip in Europe, primarily the Netherlands, over a week or two. But I'd rather rent a bike (in fact, two) than bring mine all the way from Australia.

Are there any options for 'one way' bike rentals, so that I would hire a bike (a relatively decent multi-speed one, kitted for touring), say, in Amstrerdam and drop it off a week later in Brussels? While normal for car rentals, I haven't heard of such options for bikes...

Comment: I know quite a few bike shops in Belgium and the Netherlands and never heard of a service like this. I will ask your question in a local bike shop (Antwerp) that offers rental services for good quality touring bikes tomorrow. I will keep this thread informed.

Comment: This is kind-of across the http://travel.stackexchange.com site as well.  Consider searching there too.

Comment: @Criggie, thanks, I actually managed to find [a very similar one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44693/bicycle-rental-in-netherlands-with-drop-off-in-another-city). There is a useful link to [OV fiets](http://www.ov-fiets.nl/) there, but it's not _the_ thing...

Comment: Not a cross sites duplicate but still this question might be helpful. Also check out the related questions to that one, as renting bicycles is an often asked about topic on Travel Stack Exchange: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34723/where-to-rent-a-non-city-bike-in-amsterdam-for-a-reasonable-price?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Willeke, there are leads there that may come to something...

Comment: for the price of rental, it may be worthwhile to check used bike in the Netherlands. If you are of medium/tall height, you will find plenty of good bicycles in the range of 200/300 euros (although I recommend another city, like Delft or Utrecht, or smaller town like Appledorn to look and find "the deal").
To have an idea about used bike price, check the site
https://www.marktplaats.nl/ and look for bike shops selling bikes (in the list for results click on "Bezoek website" ). Almost any dutch can speak, read and write some english (also in other cities and town than Amsterdam).

Comment: Thanks @EarlGrey, I'm considering that too. I'm also considering bringing a bike from here (where I can have a new one for 100 euros) but selling or giving it away there at the end...

Answer (score 5):

I didn't think this was possible, but Google came up with this site (in Dutch) https://www.fietsverhuur.nl

Apparently they deliver rental bikes in Belgium, The Netherlands, Germany and Luxemburg. I assume they can also arrange a pickup at a different location, if the price is right .

It isn't clear if this is just for groups, but you could [contact](https://www.fietsverhuur.nl/Contact.html) them if you want.

Comment: I enquiried them; they are indeed only for groups (normally from 10 bikes). Understandable, given that it's a local company which just drives a truck to drop off/pick up at locations, rather than a multi-branch company like car rentals...

Comment: Yes, I was afraid it would be something like that. You could take @david-richerby 's advice and take the bike on the train, or make a roundtrip. After all, Amsterdam – Brussels is only ~220 km, or maybe ~300 if you take (for instance) the coastal path.

Comment: Well, yes, there are always options, they are just not as convenient. After all, I can always take my bikes with me; it seems that even normal rent of an average touring bike for 10 days costs about half of its (new) price...

Comment: At roughly €20 a day that would mean you have a cheap bike, or you didn't find the right place ;-) E.g. https://www.macbike.nl/touring-bicycle (not affiliated, this is just one example I found)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that one. Theirs is a 21-gear bike, i.e. 3x7, which means - the cheapest possible (of this kind). I can buy one (new) like that for well under €400 here, and a slightly simpler but sufficient one for [4-days rent](https://www.kmart.com.au/product/70cm-monteray-urban-bike/2122313)...

Answer (score 4):

This seems very unlikely. It's possible for car rental because the same company has premises in both cities and they do enough volume of business that having a few cars move from place to place won't make a huge difference to them. That doesn't seem likely for bikes.

However, Brussels is only two hours from Amsterdam on the train, and you can take bikes on trains. Returning the bike to Amsterdam and getting yourself back to Brussels would only take an afternoon.

<sub>Unlikely, but possibly possible, according to [the other answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/59889/13174). I'll leave this here, though, because I think that using the train to return the bike is an option that should be mentioned.</sub>

Comment: You are very right. On top of what you said, flying to/from Amsterdam will be most likely cheaper than flying to Amsterdam and out from Bruxelles.
And the flight from Bruxelles will probably have a stopover in Amsterdam/Frankfurt, so even considering time/stress factor, it is a wise move to catch a train back to AMS

Answer (score 3):

In the end, the only option I found is [Rent a road bike](https://www.rent-a-road-bike.com/Amsterdam). They do have hybrid bikes (which are cheaper than road bikes), but they charge a fee for cross-border one-way rentals. Overall on the expensive side, but they do exactly what I asked.

Answer (score -1):

There are public rental bikes available in many major European cities Amsterdam and Brussels among them, but these are mainly locally based and meant to be used locally and not to travel between places. Most are operated via a membership system, long-term, short-term or daily, that is only valid on the local territory. The idea is that you use the bike to travel between stations, put it back in a stand and release another one when you move on.

But I think that you may find bike-shops where you can hire a bike for a longer period, although you'd most certainly have to return them to the same place.

Ad-on: Check youth-hostel websites. Some may be linked to reconditioned, second hand or rental bike schemes.

Comment: Public rental bikes aren't going to work: they need to be returned to the area they were rented in.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's what I said!